# Data Does Not Load In OnAfterRenderAsync() Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Here I have blazor server app, where I am trying to delete role and after deleting I want to load role list again and display deleted message.

But the problem is that after deletion of role delete message is displayed but role list doesnot load again.
Below is what I have done

RoleList.razor

```
@foreach (var item in roleList)
 {
   <tr>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>
         <a href="/admin/editrole/@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
         <button @onclick="()=>DeleteRole(item.Id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
 }
```

```
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await jSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("AddDataTables", new object[] { "#example" });
        if (MessageStaus.MessageId == 1)
        {
            toastService.ShowSuccess("Role successfully created");
            MessageStaus.MessageId = 0;
        }
        else if(MessageStaus.MessageId == 2)
        {
            toastService.ShowSuccess("Role successfully edited");
            MessageStaus.MessageId = 0;
        }
        else if(MessageStaus.MessageId == 3)
        {
            toastService.ShowSuccess("Role successfully deleted");
            roleList = mainService.GetAllRoles();
            StateHasChanged();
            MessageStaus.MessageId = 0;
        }          
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
```

```
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        roleList = mainService.GetAllRoles();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
```

```
    public async Task DeleteRole(string roleId)
    {
        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
        bool confirmed = await jSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
        if (confirmed)
        {
            var result = await roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);       
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                MessageStaus.MessageId = 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reload `roleList` in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  The name of the method should be a bit of a give away.  AFTERRENDER = the component has already rendered and any changes only get into the UI when the component get re-rendered.

Add your `roleList` update to `DeleteRole`.  The component won't re-render till `DeleteRole` completes.

```cs
public async Task DeleteRole(string roleId)
    {
        var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
        bool confirmed = await jSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
        if (confirmed)
        {
            var result = await roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);       
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                MessageStaus.MessageId = 3;
                // Added here to update roleList after it changes
                roleList = mainService.GetAllRoles();
            }
        }
    }
```